# Does RallyRestApi use HTTP GET or POST method?

Tags: security, rally

I am using the Java Toolkit for Rally REST API, and I am concerned about security of credentials being passed using the RallyRestApi class. Does RallyRestApi use an HTTP GET or POST method for authenticating?

Here is the usage example from the [Java Toolkit for Rally REST API](http://developer.rallydev.com/help/java-toolkit-rally-rest-api) page:

```
RallyRestApi restApi = new RallyRestApi(new URI("https://rally1.rallydev.com"), "user@company.com", "password");
```

Thanks,
Nick.

Comment: Are you asking if the API uses HTTPS when it is authenticating your username?

Comment: Who cares if it uses get or post? How is this a security concern?

Comment: I wasn't sure how the request was being made. Even if it is using HTTPS, if the username and password are appended as a query string to the end of the URL, then this would be readily available as clear text. Sounds like Kyle answered my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The toolkit uses basic auth, which basically sends the username/password in an encoded header.  As long as you are connecting to the server via SSL (https protocol rather than http) your credentials will not be passed in clear text.

Comment: Much appreciated for the explanation.